# Serving firebase functions always says the port isn't open

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

So I'm trying to serve my firebase function but every time I try to do it no matter what port I use it'll give the error: `Error: Port {{Port Here}} is not open, could not start functions emulator.`. I've searched everywhere I can think of and I can't find anyone else with this issue. I have hosting in the same folder but I've used this same setup in multiple firebase projects before with no issues. The only difference is my new PC which I built last week (This is the first firebase project I've done on it) but I don't see why that would cause something like this. I'm running serve with `firebase serve --only functions,hosting`. If I deploy the entire function and go to the site itself the function is working as expected but it can't ever be served which is very hard to work with for development. Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: If I try to serve only the hosting and not the functions it works fine, it's just functions that have this issue

Comment: I am having the same issue. Everything worked fine untill i decided to update firebase tools version... after that everything broke, i deleted everything and started again by firebase init and it now shows port not open for every port i try. Did you manage to find any solutions?

Comment: This is just after me building my new PC so I installed firebase tools and it started happening when I tried serving a function, maybe I'll try rolling back to an older version of ftools like the one on my old pc and see if that works

Comment: i found fix on stackoverflow, you need to edit firebase-tools ... type npm root -g in console. And go to that directory and go to firebase-tools and go to lib controler.js and there is something about port ... you need add +1 i forgot where try find on stackoverflow

Comment: I think this has been fixed in 7.2.4, judging by the time of your comment, they released a fix for it 10 hours ago. Was having the same issue. Uninstalled and installed wirh 7.2.4 and issue resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in `firebase-tools@7.2.4`!